# Unit testing the instance from a factory

Tags: php, unit-testing, factory

I'm trying to create a unit test for a Factory class,
but *PHPUnit* is returning me a fatal error on the creation of the Product.

> Fatal error: Class 'JsonStorage' not found

### Files structure

```
-\
    -libs
    -My
        -Storage
                -IStorage.php
                -IStorageFactory.php
                -StorageFactory.php
                -JsonStorage.php
                -FileStorage.php
    -tests
        -StorageFactoryTest.php
```

This is the

### **Creator**

```
use \tests;
namespace My\Storage;

class StorageFactory implements IStorageFactory
{
    public static function build($type)
    {
        $classname = "Storage";

        if (is_string($type)) {
            switch($type = ucfirst(strtolower(trim($type)))) {
                case "Json":    // Fall-through
                case "File":
                    $classname = $type . $classname;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new \Exception("Storage type not recognized or not yet implemented: please provide a valid type");
            }

            if (class_exists($classname)) {
                try {
                    return new $classname;
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    throw new \Exception("Cannot create Storage object: please provide a valid type");
                }
            } else {
                throw new \Exception("Class not recognized");

        }
```

### **Product of the factory**

**can be**

```
namespace My\Storage;

class FileStorage implements IStorage
{
    private $filepath;
    private $data;
    private $handle = null;

    public function __construct($filepath = null)
    {
        if (isset($filepath)) {
            $this->setPath($filepath);
        }
    }

    //....
}
```

**or (the case I'm testing)**

```
namespace My\Storage;

class JsonStorage extends FileStorage
{
    // .... additional implementations
}
```

and I have a

### **Testing class**

```
    use \tests;
    namespace My\Form\Storage;

    require_once _DIR_ . "\..\My\Form\Storage\IStorage.php";
    require_once .... <all the other classes>.....
    require_once

class StorageFactoryTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function testCanBuildJSON()
    {
        $s = StorageFactory::build("JSON");

        $this->assertInstanceOf($s, "IStorage");  // Or better directly 'JsonStorage'?
    }
}
```

Maybe is something wrong with the namespaces, but I cannot understand why the *JsonStorage* class is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easy (but took me a lot..)

I checked that the class was declared with `get_declared_classes()`.
Then I read that [`assertInstanceOf` needs a *full qualified namespace* if executed inside a namespace](http://blog.scripticles.com/2013/06/phpunit-assertinstanceof-not-working.html).

So I just changed the

### Creator

```
$classname = __NAMESPACE__."\\".$classname;

if (class_exists($classname)) {
    try {
        return new $classname;
    } //...
```

and the

### Test

```
public function testCanBuildJSON()
{
    $s = StorageFactory::build("JSON");

    $this->assertInstanceOf(__NAMESPACE__."\\JsonStorage", $s);
}
```

Hope it could help someone.

PS - *Feel free to add details or suggestions for better practices*